# Reference to Delete button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to refer to delete link button in a GridView when both edit and delete buttons are located in the first column of the GridView and AutoGenerateDeleteButton property of GridView is true. I'm referring to it as:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
            {
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Are you sure to delete this row?'))return   false;";
            }
        }
    }
```

Code runs fine but when I delete a record in GridView1, it doesn't confirm it and deletes the record. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML of just one row?

Comment: @RenniePet WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried in my system, when i tried to debug and look into e.Row.Cells[0].Controls, i found that delete button exist at index 2, so you can attach delete js validation there.

```
((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2]).Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Are you sure to delete this row?'))return   false;";
```

One suggestion, 
you can also add this check , instead of RowState.

```
     if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
 }
```

Comment: Your code works locally but after publishing it to server, its not working on server. Any idea why?

Comment: can you debug there, i mean just put response.write( ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2]).Text) and respons.end, to see, what you are getting there!